# Monitor spring caching

Tags: spring, caching, spring-mvc

I've used spring cache abstraction and it works pretty well. And Springs' *SimpleCacheManager*  is used as the cache storage.

Now it is bit difficult to test the application with caching and cache eviction, as there exists a considerable number of caching enabled methods. If any one can suggest a way to monitor the cache it'll be really helpful.